# Using PayPal and zoho creator for credit card charge

Tags: post, paypal, credit-card, zoho

I would like to make CC charges via calls from zoho creator to PayPal.

When looking at this example am not sure how to construct my Post [Deluge script]: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

Specifically, am not sure what is this: Authorization:Bearer
Is this related to the REST API credentials from PayPal?

Zoho construct POST as URL + Map as variable etc.

Any pointers are appreciated,

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Form Setting--->Enable the Payment option--->Enable Paypal Id and Currency type. 
[Payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo8iT.jpg)

https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/forms/accept-payments-through-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are planning to achieve this via Zoho Creator. Zoho Creator's Post URL supports Header info (to pass Authorization:Bearer). If you are thinking to store the credit card info on a Zoho Creator Form and then use it in the Post url task, it is not allowed. Refer to Zoho Creator terms (Phishing section) at https://www.zoho.com/creator/terms.html

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar system that doesn't store credit card details on zoho (just passes them securely to the payment gateway). I built it using html and javascript that is hosted on amazon s3 using the technique I outlined on the following page: http://www.lighthouselogic.com/cross-domain-ajax-requests-to-zoho-creator/